# C++ Code Analysis complaining about critical section lock and release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, code-analysis, critical-section

I have the following situation:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;

class NF3DLock
    {
    public:
#pragma prefast( suppress:26166, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
        FORCEINLINE _Acquires_lock_(CriticalSection) NF3DLock(void)  { EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); }
#pragma prefast( suppress:26165, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
        FORCEINLINE _Releases_lock_(CriticalSection) ~NF3DLock(void) { LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); }
    };
```

This snippet compiles perfectly and I get no warnings from Code Analysis under Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. But if I change it to:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION* GetCriticalSection(void)
{
    static CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;
    return &CriticalSection;
}

class NF3DLock
{
    public:
#pragma prefast( suppress:26166, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
        FORCEINLINE _Acquires_lock_(GetCriticalSection()) NF3DLock(void)  { EnterCriticalSection(GetCriticalSection()); }
#pragma prefast( suppress:26165, "Thread safeness is enabeled." )
        FORCEINLINE _Releases_lock_(GetCriticalSection()) ~NF3DLock(void) { LeaveCriticalSection(GetCriticalSection()); }
    };
```

Code Analysis says:

```
e:\new frontiers\newfrontiers3d\header files\state.h(52): warning C28285: For function '{ctor}' 'return' syntax error in 'SAL_acquires_lock(NF3DGetCriticalSection())' near '())'.
e:\new frontiers\newfrontiers3d\header files\state.h(54): warning C28285: For function '{dtor}' 'return' syntax error in 'SAL_releases_lock(NF3DGetCriticalSection())' near '())'.
```

Does anybody know a way to fix this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your second example is not thread safe. If two threads call `GetCriticalSection()` simultaneously as the first instance that it is called, then there's a race condition on the initialisation on the `static CRITICAL_SECTION` object. It may not be related to the error you're getting, but it's an issue you should consider.

Comment: In the first version you pass an object to `_Acquires_lock_`. In the second version you pass a pointer.

Comment: gigaplex, how can I make it be thread safe? Should I access the critical section using another critical section that enters and leaves when returning the first one, by declaring a NF3DLock object in 'GetCriticalSection', at the beginning of the function?

Comment: Bo Persson, I know I pass a pointer to _Acquires_lock_. What do you recommend me to do? To change 'GetCriticalSection' to CRITICAL_SECTION GetCriticalSection(void)?

Comment: In neither version have you initialized the critical section. This must be done in some protected point, i.e. before you start any other threads, or in DllMain PROCESS_ATTACH. You can achieve this either explicitly or with a static initializer.

Comment: I actually initialise the critical section, but I didn't post the code responsible for it because the problem isn't located there.